# CollectionViewCells change with scroll

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview

I made a collection view so that the user can select multiple choices and with each choice the cell changes its background, the problem is when for example I select the first cell and then scroll down the painted cells change, and others are painted instead, and this keep changing every time I scroll, this is the code I use for creating the collection view and for painting the cells

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell:ServiciosCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellServicios", for: indexPath) as! ServiciosCollectionViewCell
        var borderColor: CGColor! = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        var borderWidth: CGFloat = 0
            borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
            borderWidth = 1 
        cell.imageView.layer.borderWidth = borderWidth
        cell.imageView.layer.borderColor = borderColor
        let servicio = ServiciosArray[indexPath.row] as! NSDictionary
        cell.serviciosLabel.text = servicio["nombre"] as? String
        return cell
    }

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at:indexPath)
    let servicio = ServiciosArray[indexPath.row] as! NSDictionary
    if let result_number = servicio["id_servicio"] as? NSNumber
    {
        if ServiciosSeleccionadosArray.contains(result_number){
            ServiciosSeleccionadosArray.remove(result_number)
            cell?.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        }else{
            ServiciosSeleccionadosArray.add(result_number)
            cell?.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.72, green:0.33, blue:0.56, alpha:1.0)
        }
    }}
```

I control which cell to paint depending on the array "ServiciosSeleccionadosArray" (the value of this array don't change, only the painting).

Comment: This is a result of cell re-use.  You will need to restructure your code so that in `cellForItemAt` you know if that cell index is currently selected and style it there as well.

Comment: @KevinDiTraglia Can you please give me some hints on how to do that? or I have to do the same thing I do in didselect in cellForItemAt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feel free to refactor to reduce code duplication, but the quickest fix is to just put a similar check in `cellForItemAt` that you already have within `didSelectItemAt`:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell:ServiciosCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellServicios", for: indexPath) as! ServiciosCollectionViewCell
    var borderColor: CGColor! = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    var borderWidth: CGFloat = 0
        borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        borderWidth = 1 
    cell.imageView.layer.borderWidth = borderWidth
    cell.imageView.layer.borderColor = borderColor
    let servicio = ServiciosArray[indexPath.row] as! NSDictionary
    cell.serviciosLabel.text = servicio["nombre"] as? String

    if let result_number = servicio["id_servicio"] as? NSNumber {
        if ServiciosSeleccionadosArray.contains(result_number){
            cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.72, green:0.33, blue:0.56, alpha:1.0)
        } else {
            cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        }
    }
    return cell
}
```

Comment: @AlfonsoMoraDelaCalle, ah makes sense, I'll update my answer.